# How to make a customized menu for Delphi's WebBrowser?

Tags: delphi, menu, browser

Is it possible to make a customized menu for the `WebBrowser` control?

I want to disable some existing items and add some new items.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this implementing the [`IDocHostUIHandler.ShowContextMenu`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753264%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method for the TWebBrowser Component, when you override this method, the TWebBrowser control will call your customized menu, check this article [`How to customize the TWebBrowser user interface (part 4 of 6)`](http://www.delphidabbler.com/articles?article=18&part=4) to learn how override this method from delphi and then check this article from the MSDN [`WebBrowser Customization (Part 2)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa770042.aspx) to see how customize the menu.